# Fabric - Project path environment

Tags: python, django, deployment, fabric

Let's consider this **fabfile**

```
def syncdb():
  print(green("Database Synchronization ..."))
  with cd('/var/www/project'):
    sudo('python manage.py syncdb', user='www-data')

def colstat():
  print(green("Collecting Static Files..."))
  with cd('/var/www/project'):
    sudo('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput', user='www-data')

def httpdrst():
  print(green("Restarting Apache..."))
  sudo('apachectl restart')

def srefresh():
  colstat()
  syncdb()
  httpdrst()
```

The `srefresh` directive calls all the others, certain of which `with cd(...)`

What would be the best way to have this 'cd path' in a variable ?

```
def colstat():
  with cd(env.remote['path']):

def srefresh():
  env.remote['path'] = '/var/www/project'
  colstat()
  syncdb()
  httpdrst()
```

Something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just pass the variable to the functions as an argument.

```
def syncdb(path):
  print(green("Database Synchronization ..."))
  with cd(path):
    sudo('python manage.py syncdb', user='www-data')

def colstat(path):
  print(green("Collecting Static Files..."))
  with cd(path):
    sudo('python manage.py collectstatic --noinput', user='www-data')

def httpdrst():
  print(green("Restarting Apache..."))
  sudo('apachectl restart')

def srefresh():
  path = '/var/www/project'
  colstat(path)
  syncdb(path)
  httpdrst()
```

Comment: This should work just fine on Fabric. If you still want to call them with `fab command` without needing to specify the arguments, just give them a default.

Comment: Working, but the problem is that I can't call `syncdb`, `colstat` independently anymore

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's a good practice but it seems to do the job with that

```
env.remote_path = '/var/www/project'

def colstat():
  with cd(env.remote_path):

#...

def srefresh():
  env.remote_path = '/var/www/other_project'
  pushpull()
  colstat()
#...
```